# Using ipfs in javascipt: how to read an object the same way as dumpign it to file from command line and reading the file?

Tags: node.js, ipfs, apache-arrow

I have some arrow file that I am trying to read in javascript. Dumping it to file via the commanline: `ipfs get HASH` and then

```
fs = require('fs')
a = fs.readFileSync(HASH)
da = arrow.Table.from(a)
```

works fine.

Loading the cid (HASH)

```
ipfs = require('ipfs')    
ipfs.create({repo: String(Math.random() + Date.now()) }).then(x=>node=x).then(
    node=>node.object.get(HASH)
).then(x=>data=x)
```

Gives my something that has a `data.Data` buffer in some other format and it does not load into an arrow Table in the same way. How can I get the bytes in the same was as the readFileSync?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you need to use the ipfs cat method and that returns an async iterator so there is a small step to be aware of to get that into the arrow table.

I am not sure if there is a direct method for the get.

```py
async function docat() {
    var out = []
    for await (const result of node.cat(has)) {
        out.push(result)
    }
    return out
}
```